# Fixed sorting choice for all communities

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I usually like to navigate through different sites. When I do so, I usually sort the questions with respect to number of upvotes. In Android app, when I pick my sorting choice, it is applied to all sites. The same feature in iOS would also be very convenient.